# Azure DevOps - Cannot add a new link because this will exceed the maximum number

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

How to increase limit to links a worklineItem in Azure DevOps VSTS.

Getting info's in TFS. Not in Azure devOps.. can any expert help me to solve.

Error:
TF237201: Cannot add a new link because this will exceed the maximum number of links allowed. The limit is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for TFS: [Error TF237201 when you try to add a new link to a work item in Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/devops/error-add-link-work-item).

As you can see, it can be resolved through SQL updates... I think for Azure DevOps Service, you have to contact with the support team:

[image]